# Cant get Jade syntax correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have this jade layout files but everytime I try to render it I get 
  "unexpected text ;" on backgound: url(...). I am not sure how to fix. I have looked at other example and they do it like this.

```
doctype html
 html
head
style
  body {
    background: url('!{imageURI}');
    background-size:75%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
body
h1 Tweets
h1 #{tweet.text}
h1  @#{tweet.user.screen_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your pug template:

1. Leading space before html
2. Missing dot after `style`.

The correct template can looks so:

```
doctype html
html
head
body
style.
  body {
    background: url('!{imageURI}');
    background-size: 75%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
h1 Tweets
h1 #{tweet.text}
h1 @#{tweet.user.screen_name}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. By any chance do you have a recommendation for a good jade documentation?

Comment: Currently it names _pug_. The good place to study it is the [official site](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), to test pug templates use [online editor](http://html2jade.org/)